# Laravel routes not working after login

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to Laravel and just started building my first app. I am using Laravel 5.2.5. I was following the laracast video in order to implement authentication. When I start the application for the first time, I can access /auth/register, /auth/login and /auth/logout. Register and Login work fine. Register creates an entry in my User table and /auth/login lets me login with that user. After successful login, I try to logout. When I try to access /auth/logout, I get an NotFoundHttpException. I get the same exception when I try to access /auth/login and /auth/register. At this point I can only access welcome and test pages. On the welcome page I am displaying the currently logged user and I can see that he is still logged in. I didn't change any code in the rest of the files.

Here is my routes.php code:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function () {
    Route::get('welcome', function () {
        return view('welcome');
    });
    Route::get('test','TestController@index');

    Route::get('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogin');
    Route::post('auth/login', 'Auth\AuthController@postLogin');
    Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');

// Registration routes...
    Route::get('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@getRegister');
    Route::post('auth/register', 'Auth\AuthController@postRegister');
});
```

AuthenticationController:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ThrottlesLogins;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers;

class AuthController extends Controller
{  

    use AuthenticatesAndRegistersUsers, ThrottlesLogins;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login / registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/welcome';

    /**
     * Create a new authentication controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => 'required|max:255',
            'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
            'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

login.blade.php:

```
<form method="POST" action="/auth/login">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}

    <div>
        Email
        <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
    </div>

    <div>
        Password
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password">
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="checkbox" name="remember"> Remember Me
    </div>

    <div>
        <button type="submit">Login</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

register.blade.php:

```
<form method="POST" action="/auth/register">
    {!! csrf_field() !!}

    <div>
        Name
        <input type="text" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">
    </div>

    <div>
        Email
        <input type="email" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
    </div>

    <div>
        Password
        <input type="password" name="password">
    </div>

    <div>
        Confirm Password
        <input type="password" name="password_confirmation">
    </div>

    <div>
        <button type="submit">Register</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

welcome.blade.php:

```
            <div class="title">Laravel 5</div>
            <div>{{\Auth::user()}}</div>
```

Comment: What does your middleware "web" do? The exception means, that you do not have a route for that request, maybe you send with POST and check for GET?

Comment: @derdida It's standard Laravel 5.2 group middleware

Comment: Well I write the URL directly in the browser, so I am pretty sure that it is a GET.

Comment: Ah thx Marcin, i am still on 5.1 LTS ;)

Comment: When you access those pages, are you being redirected to `'/'`?

Comment: Yes, I get the exception and the URL is changed to /.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Long story short: It's because you don't have the `'/'` route registered.

Longer explanation: I'll first answer your `NotFoundHttpException` when you try to access `/auth/login` and `/auth/register`.

In your `AuthController`, you will see this line of code:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
}
```

This bit of code basically ensures that only guests (or non-authenticated users) have access unless it comes to the logout method.

What is this "guest" middleware? If you look inside `app/Http/Kernel.php`, you will see this line of code:

```
'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
```

The "guest" is basically an alias for the `RedirectIfAuthenticated` class. Inside that class, you will see this line of code:

```
if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
    return redirect('/');
}
```

You see that if the user is already authenticated, they will be redirected to the `'/'` page. Since you don't have that route registered, you get the `NotFoundHttpException`. You can either register that route in your routes file or you can change the route inside your `RedirectIfAuthenticated` class.

Next, you are getting that same exception when you try to logout for the same reason. When you try to logout, it will trigger this bit of code:

```
public function logout()
{
    Auth::logout();

    return redirect(property_exists($this, 'redirectAfterLogout') ? $this->redirectAfterLogout : '/');
}
```

In other words, you will be redirected to the `'/'` page, which you don't have registered. If you want to redirect to another page rather than the `'/'` page, add this line of code to your `AuthController`.

```
protected $redirectAfterLogout = '/some-other-route';
```

Comment: I am sorry for the late response and thanks a lot for the reply. However, when I tried to logout the function Auth::logout() was never called, because of the route not being accessible at that moment. I solved my problem by calling logout from another route.